# People with direct edit privileges should be able to single handedly approve edit suggestions

Tags: discussion, feature-request

As the title says. I don't think it makes much sense to have a system where someone who could directly without needing approval edit something needing 2 other people of the same kind to approve a single edit suggestion.

They could just edit in the suggestion directly if they felt like it, why need 3 of them to approve a suggested edit then?

Comment: Because lots of people just like to click "approve" without looking at the edit.

Comment: It's rare to see a pending edit that can't be improved, which obviates the problem.

Comment: Wouldn't we all like to single-handedly mark this as a duplicate.  Hehe.  Having such powers is a very questionable "privilege" btw, when there's something to complain about they'll always know where to turn.

Answer (score 2):

I disagree.

At TZHX [pointed out](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/308960/people-with-direct-edit-privileges-should-be-able-to-single-handedly-approve-edi#comment263840_308960), a lot of suggested edits get accepted while they shouldn't.
All these reviews are voted on by people with [at least 2k rep](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/edit).

Giving every single 2k rep user the ability to single-handedly approve / reject will not solve any problems (The suggested edits queue cleans out quickly)